# Array to functions in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

The normal method I use to pass one-dimensional array  to a function is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5 

void function(int *ptr_array, int size) 
{
  int index;
  printf("Destination array contents: ");
  for(index=0;index<size;index++)
  {
     printf("%d ",ptr_array[index]);
  }
}

int main()
{
   int array[ARRAY_SIZE]={1,2,3,4,5};
   function(array,ARRAY_SIZE);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I did realize that the function accepting the argument can also follow as `void function(int ptr_array[],int size)` (or) `void function(int ptr_array[5],int size)`.In this scenario the arguement passed is a `int *` but received in `int []`. So the questions are

- It looks to me that compiler must do a **cast of the accepted argument in the function**.How does the array index impacts on the cast?
- If it was a 2D array's base address that is passed  to the function, what is the correct type for accepting the arguments in `int[][]` form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/1689451 shows a lot of discussion about this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are synonymous with `T *a`; `a` is a pointer type, not an array type, regardless of whether you use `[]` or `[N]` or `*`.

[Chapter and verse:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> #### 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualiﬁers (if any) are those speciﬁed within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the ﬁrst element of an array with at least as many
> elements as speciﬁed by the size expression.

Why would that be the case?  This is why:

> #### 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> `register` storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

In the call to `function`, the *expression* `array` has type "5-element array of `int`"; by the rule in 6.3.2.1/3, it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `int`", and its value is the address of the first element (`&array[0]`); this pointer value is what gets passed to `function`.

If `array` had been declared as `int array[5][5]`, then the expression `array` would be converted from "5-element array of 5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to 5-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[5]`, and your function declaration would look like

```
void function(int (*array)[5], int size)
```

which could also be written as

```
void function(int array[][5], int size)
```

or

```
void function(int array[5][5], int size)
```

Note that in this case, the size of the outer dimension *is not optional*; it must be specified so that the compiler knows the size of the type being pointed to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the context now, except the **"type qualifier"** stuff that is explained in the standards.

Answer (score 1):

All arrays can be implicitly casted to pointers of the same type as the array, but not the other way around. That's why it works to pass an array to a function accepting a pointer or assigning an array to a pointer, but you can't assign a pointer to an array.

As for your second question, you either has to have the argument as a double array (i.e. `type array[][]`) or a pointer to an array (i.e. `type (*array)[]`). In this case a pointer to a pointer will *not* work as it's something else.

Comment: I am so glad for this simple, concise explanation. I keep seeing C code that does this and not being able to understand why it's acceptable - no longer. :)

Answer (score 1):

> It looks to me that compiler must do a cast of the accepted argument
>   in the function.How does the array index impacts on the cast?

Except in some situations (utilisation as operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and unary `&` operators, according to C11 standard), an array is evaluated as a pointer to its first element. Moreover, the following forms are equivalent (in the case of function parameters):

```
void function(int ptr_array[], int size);
void function(int *ptr_array, int size);
```

Therefore, there is no really "cast" of the arguments; the array is implicitly converted to a pointer, and it matches with the argument type.

> If it was a 2D array's base address that is passed to the function, what is the correct type for accepting the arguments in int[][] form?

The following forms are among other correct:

```
void f(int t[][SIZE]);
void f(int (*t)[SIZE]);
```